# Streaming video from OBS to rtmp server running on heroku and using node-media-server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, rtmp

I've been working on this Twitch like application using react, redux, node media server and json server. It allows users to directly stream video/audio by configured their OBS to the servers URL with the Stream Key equal to the ID of the stream created within the react app. Which can be found on the ending URL of the stream you are viewing.

You can view my full repo at https://github.com/XorinNebulas/Streamy

You can also view my current deployed version of the site on Heroku at https://streamy-app.herokuapp.com/

Here is my configuration for node-media-server located in streams/rtmpserver/index.js

```
const NodeMediaServer = require("node-media-server");

const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 8000;

const config = {
  rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 30,
    ping_timeout: 60
  },
  http: {
    port: HTTP_PORT,
    allow_origin: "*"
  }
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config);
nms.run();
```

Everything works well when running the project locally, I simply go into my OBS stream settings, using a URL of rtmp://localhost/live with Stream Key equal to the ID of the stream.

However, after deploying my node app to Heroku, I am uncertain of what server URL I should be using. I also want to point out that node-media-server is successfully running on Heroku. Using `heroku logs --tail` I got back

```
[INFO] Node Media Server v2.1.2
[1] 8/23/2019 17:22:22 78 [INFO] Node Media Rtmp Server started on port: 1935
[1] 8/23/2019 17:22:22 78 [INFO] Node Media Http Server started on port: 8000
[1] 8/23/2019 17:22:22 78 [INFO] Node Media WebSocket Server started on port: 8000
```

So far I've tried simple approaches like modifying the URL in OBS by replacing localhost with my websites name `rtmp://streamy-app.herokuapp.com/live`

I expected my OBS to start publishing to my Heroku deployed app on port 1935, however after clicking start streaming in OBS i got this message

> Failed to connect to server
>
> The connection timed out. Make sure you've configured a valid streaming >service and no firewall is blocking the connection.

I would truly appreciate any suggestions, been working on this for days.

Comment: If it's on port 1935 you'll need to point your OBS to that port. `rtmp://streamy-app.herokuapp.com:1935/live` by not adding the port number, it just assumes you want port 80.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I still seem to be getting the same error message. I even tried disabling my firewall. Perhaps this is an issue with Heroku not allowing outside connections?

Comment: It could be a firewall issue. Are you also including a stream name? `tmp://streamy-app.herokuapp.com:1935/live/streamname` or just by filling in the stream name field in OBS.

Comment: No, i do however use a stream key equal to the id of the stream, which I can then retrieve thru flv with url ```/live/${id}.flv``` but my main issue is first trying to make sure that OBS streams to my Heroku app.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking. You don't need the port number in the url since the protocol is RTMP. The stream key is needed in OBS to stream to your Heroku app. I just created my own instance with the above code and it works well.

Comment: After some reading, it looks like that port is closed unless you contact heroku

Comment: I'm a little confused, your saying it worked early using ```rtmp://streamy-app.herokuapp.com/live``` in addition to the stream key, but now ill have to contact Heroku because the ports closed? Which port specifically, 1935 for rtmp or 8000 for http. My logs tell me their running fine, but maybe their still not accessible. Also i tried running ```heroku open``` since the app probably went to sleep, maybe that had something to do with it as well.

Comment: No, I used my own server.

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify ```rtmp://streamy-app.herokuapp.com/live``` would have worked if the port was not closed by Heroku right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: heroku is actually supposed to tell you what port to bind to through enviorment variables I think

Comment: @XorinNebula did you manage to figure this out? Facing the same issue right now. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, reading this later. Heroku support says that they only allow 80 and 443 HTTP/S ports and they do not officially support RTMP. I'm probably going to opt for Docker + AWS.

Comment: Late to the party, but @ManiNilchiani is correct, in that only ports 80 and 443 are available to connect to. In saying this though, it may not necessarily be the port that your app is running on (assuming you're using `process.env.PORT`). I (blindly) guess what you'd need to do is bind your RTMP server to `process.env.port` and then point OBS to `rtmp://streamy-app.herokuapp.com:80/live`. This is a guess, though, because I don't know if Heroku will block any RTMP requests/connects and only "whitelist" HTTP and HTTPS requests - even if that is a thing...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the RTMP protocol is not supported by heroku, whatever the port is 1935 or 80. So even the RTMP server listen at 80, it doesn't work neither.

There is a workaround, to use [RTMPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol#HTTP_tunneling_(RTMPT)), POST HTTP-FLV, or POST HTTP-HLS, all there are HTTP(S) based protocols. Use a server to covert the FLV/HLS to other live streaming protocol. It might work on heroku.

> Note: As I know, there is no nodejs RTMPT or POST HTTP-FLV/HLS server, but there is some c++ server. I don't know how many users want to build live streaming server on heroku, but obviously docker(or like AWS LightSail) is a proper solution.

In future, we might use HTTP/3, QUIC or WebTransport to publish live streaming, in HTTP/HTTPS way. But right now, at 2021.12, it's not available.