# How to send a RTMP request with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rtmp, live-streaming

I have a simple nodejs + node-media-server RTMP server running and I am studying and trying and trying to create a live stream app in Swift, however I am having some issues on how to send non http request in Swift,

Here's my LiveStream class code:

```swift
  
import Foundation

final class LiveStream: NSObject {
    private let streamName: String
    
    private var outputStream: OutputStream!
    private var inputStream: InputStream!
    private var streamTask: URLSessionStreamTask!
    
    private lazy var netService: NetService = {
        let service = NetService(domain: "streaming-course.herokuapp.com", type: "_rtmp._tcp.", name: streamName, port: 1935)
        service.delegate = self
        return service
    }()
    
    init(streamName: String) {
        self.streamName = streamName
        super.init()
        configure()
    }
    
    func write(data: Data) {
        var bytesWrittenLength = 0
        data.withUnsafeBytes { unsafeRawPointer in
            guard let uint8Pointer = unsafeRawPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress else { return }
            bytesWrittenLength += outputStream.write(uint8Pointer, maxLength: data.count)
        }
        
        print("Bytes written:", bytesWrittenLength)
    }
    
    func write(pointer: UnsafeRawPointer?) {
        var bytesWrittenLength = 0
        guard let uint8Pointer = pointer?.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 1024) else { return }
        bytesWrittenLength += outputStream.write(uint8Pointer, maxLength: 1024)
        
        print("Bytes written:", bytesWrittenLength)
    }
    
    
}

private extension LiveStream {
    func configure() {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        streamTask = session.streamTask(with: netService)
        streamTask.resume()
        streamTask.captureStreams()
    }
}

extension LiveStream: NetServiceDelegate {
    func netService(_ sender: NetService, didAcceptConnectionWith inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) {
        print("Connection accepted")
    }
}

extension LiveStream: URLSessionStreamDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, streamTask: URLSessionStreamTask, didBecome inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) {
        self.outputStream = outputStream
        self.inputStream = inputStream
        
        inputStream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .default)
        outputStream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .default)
        
        inputStream.open()
        outputStream.open()
    }
}
```

The current state of my app is crash right at initialisation with logged error message:

**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNetService _internalNetService]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2801e6640'**

So I am not initialising NetService correctly + plus I have no idea if using `URLSessionStreamTask` is really the way to go when sending a `rmtp request`...

Does anyone have any idea Why Am I getting this error? and If going towards the correct direction with this class setup?

I appreciate your attention,
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try HaishinKit for RTMP streaming

Answer (score 0):

Also note that heroku is not able to run RTMP server, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70493485/17679565).

Because heroku only support HTTP/HTTPS protocol, while RTMP is TCP based protocol. RTMP server should be deployed by server based platform, like AWS ECS, or K8s, or DigitalOcean droplet.